# Is there a smooth $4$-manifold homeomorphic but not diffemorphic to $CP^2$?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds, differential-topology, open-problems

Is there a smooth $4$-manifold homeomorphic but not diffemorphic to $CP^2$? Are there known non-smooth examples homeomorphic $CP^2$?

Comment: Your question is answered on the "smooth structure" Wikipedia page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_structure

As it's an open problem, moreover of the type we likely won't resolve quickly, I'm voting to close.  Please click on the "faq" and "how to ask" links above for further context. 


Comment: Dear Yang, I'm afraid famous open problems are off-topic on MathOverflow.  This site seems to work best for questions where you think an expert somewhere might know the answer.

Comment: Yang, I really don't think the second part of your question is meaningful. If one constructs a manifold homeomorphic to $CP^2$, but the construction is only of a topological manifold, then one can smooth it by declaring the homeomorphism to be a diffeomorphism. I don't think there's anything more to be said.

Comment: Can you always smooth topological 4-manifold? I know that not all the topological 4 manifolds are smoothable. 

Comment: For example, the Freedman's famous $E_8$ manifold is not smoothable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_manifold

Comment: I think extra argument is needed to prove that. The claim all compact topological 4 manifolds are smoothable is NOT correct. More  examples follows from Donaldson's Theorem.

Comment: There are plenty of non-smoothable 4-manifolds. However, one that is homeomorphic to $CP^2$ has a smooth structure: that of $CP^2$.

Comment: My question was is that is there a construction which doesn't have a natural smooth structure. My guess is that there is no such 4-manifold. The question would be more interesting if I consider the same intersection form of $CP^2$, rather than the homeomorphism type of $CP^2$.

Comment: note that Yau has shown in 1977 that if a complex surface is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}P^2$ then it is biholomorphic to it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a notorious open problem. For the moment the simplest *compact* four-manifold that is announced to admit (infinite number of) exotic smooth structures is $S^2\times S^2$. This result is contained here : http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3346

I have to say that I am not at all an expert in the area 
(also it seems that the above paper is not yet published). On the other hand there are several published papers showing that $CP^2\sharp 3\overline{CP^2}$ admit exotic smooth structures.

Also, it might be worth to recall that by a theorem of Yau a complex surface homeomrophic to $CP^2$ always has the standard smooth structure (in other words $CP^2$ admits a unique holomorphic structure up to bi-homolorphism). While for $S^2\times S^2$ this is still unknown (is there a surface of general type homeomorphic to $S^2\times S^2$?)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. What about the second part of my question? Are there non-smooth examples homeo to $CP^2$?

Comment: It's not clear what the second part of your question means.  Do you mean, "Are there constructions of bare topological 4-manifolds that are known to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^2$ that don't have any obvious or natural candidate for a smooth structure?"

Comment: Yes, that was my question. 

Comment: I did google about this, and find out a lot known about exotic smooth and symplectic structures on $CP^2#\n(-CP^2)$ for $n>1$. Best records ($n = 2,3,4$) are due to A. Akhmedov and B. D. Park and proved in the following published papers:

http://www.springerlink.com/content/b27550567381396t/

http://www.springerlink.com/content/901221167510182u/

The cases $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ are open as Dmitri pointed out.



Comment: What about $\mathbb{R}^4$? This is a simpler 4-manifold than $S^2\times S^2$, and has uncountably many exotic smooth structures.

Comment: Perhaps you meant _compact_ smooth manifold?

Comment: Yes, the original question was for compact and simply connected 
case. The examples mentioned above have the smallest possible Euler characteristics which admit exotic smooth structures. It open for 4-manifolds $S^4$, $CP^2$, and $CP^2#(-CP)^2$.