# Are there exotic $S^2\times S^2$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

On 2010 AKHMEDOV and PARK claimed there are infinitely many exotic smooth structures on $S^2\times S^2$, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3346

Then Rasmussen posted a paper : Perfect Morse functions and exotic $S^2 \times  S^2$'s http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4674 But he withdrawn his paper, here is his note:

> > The main theorem of the paper shows that a smooth manifold which is homeomorphic to S^2xS^2 and has nonvanishing Ozsvath-Szabo invariant does not admit a perfect Morse function. I am withdrawing the paper because it is unclear to me if such a manifold exists.

Did I understand correctly that the first paper mentioned above had a gap? Which means one don't know whether there exists exotic smooth structure on $S^2\times S^2$.

Comment: Rasmussen showed that the manifold constructed by AKHMEDOV and PARK has non-vanishing Osvath-Szabo invariant. But the reason he withdrawn is he don't know if it exists. or did I miss something?

Comment: As far as I understand, some experts claim that there is indeed a (serious) gap in this paper related to the computation of fundamental group of the constructed manifold. Since I have not red the paper I don't know if there is a problem there and if there is, what it is.

Comment: Oszvath-Szabo and Seiberg-Witten invariants are conjecturally equivalent for $4$-manifolds. Their equivalence for $3$-manifolds  has been recently established. 

Comment: related closed question:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73001/is-there-a-smooth-4-manifold-homeomorphic-but-not-diffemorphic-to-cp2-clos